# Relation between equivariant geometry and representation theory (of geometric objects)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebroids

Equivariant geometry studies "manifolds" with an extra structure $G\times M\rightarrow M$.

Representation theory studies "Lie algebroids" with an extra structure $\Gamma(M,A)\times \Gamma(M,E)\rightarrow \Gamma(M,E)$.

There may be other similarities, but, I am not able to collect them  together now.

Question is the following:

> Is any relation between equivariant geometry (in appropriate sense) and representation theory (of appropriate geometric objects)?

I do not have any further data to support my guess. I will add more details if and when I find something interesting.

Comment: I guess $G$ is a group and $M$ is a manifold in your definition of equivariant geometry, and so $M$ is probably also a manifold in your definition of representation theory.  What are $A$ and $E$?

Comment: @LSpice sorry. I am not saying I know how to relate A and E with equivariant geometry. It is just a hunch.. $E\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle, and $A\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle with an extra structure on $\Gamma(M,A)$..

Comment: A manifold with an action of a Lie group gives rise to the associated Lie groupoid, which in its turn gives rise to the associated Lie algebroid.  This gives a functor from manifolds with an action of a Lie group to Lie algebroids.  Is there any other aspect of this correspondence that you are looking for?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Every Lie group action on a manifold would give a Lie groupoid and that in turn gives a Lie algebroid.. That is not what I am referring to here.. I am thinking that the "data" of group action in equivariant set up looks similar to "data" of representation (for example of Lie algebroids).. I am trying to see if there is any relation between these two notions..